# How to access special key symbols on Magic Keyboard UK layout used with Windows 10

Tags: keyboard, magic-keyboard-ipad

I am using the Apple Magic Keyboard version for the UK using a Dell laptop running Windows 10. I am having the following struggles,

i) I cant seem to access the `#` (which is part of the key for `3` and which also has the `£` symbol above it.) The `#` seems to be a third symbol available on the key but I cant seem to access it. I dont know what combination of keystrokes would acccess this special character.

ii) I have the same problem as i) above but for the `€` symbol which is on the `2` key which has the `@` symbol above it.

iii) On the `2` key there is the `@` symbol above it but it's not correctly mapped. When I select it I get the `"` instead. The `"` and the `@` seem to be the assigned the wrong way round on my system. How do I correct this please ?

Not sure if it's a good idea to present 3 problems on the one post or if I should create 3 separate posts - one for each issue - its just they all seem closely related.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Robbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you're fighting several paradigm difference here.

1. Windows doesn't use the Alt [Opt] key to provide a third layer of characters, instead it has a very limited range of 'extra' characters that can be called by holding the ALtGr key [which the Mac doesn't have physically on the keyboard.] Windows will often accept AltGr if you simultaneously press the **right** Ctrl and Alt/Opt keys simultaneously.

This is the additional range of characters you get this way -

[image]

2. UK Windows keyboards have both @ and " swapped, compared to Apple UK keyboards. They agree on US keyboards - so to swap these you need to set your Input Language on Windows to US or US International.
   This will have a secondary effect of replacing the UK Pound sign, £, with the US Pound # [which Brits are more likely to call hash or hashtag]

Another quirk of US International is that if you press " followed by a letter it will add an umlaut, such as ö, ' will add a grave accent, à. To avoid this, you tap the spacebar afterwards instead of a letter.

I don't think you will solve your F-Keys issue unless you can persuade something like AutoHotKey to map them for you. This is something I have no experience with, sorry.

Comment: thank you - thats a great answer. I tried you're trick for 1. and found the € symbol mapped above the 4 key - which is how you've shown it in your photo. 
The fact that there are these 3 items are really quite a niggle. I am surprised that there hasnt been a mapping produced specifically for this issue. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: mappings may be produced based on the numbers who need it - perhaps you are doing something "odd"...

Comment: If you run Windows on Parallels on the Mac, they provide extra keyboard layouts that can get around a lot of this. I would imagine the Boot Camp additional software would do it on a Mac running Windows too - but Apple don't really support Win at all outside of those parameters & you need a Mac to get the Boot Camp Win software, afaik.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines that its surprising that no one from the Microsoft Windows camp has developed a keyboard mapping for the Magic keyboard to use with MS Windows. The mapping might for instance re-map the Magic keyboard to conform to existing mappings like you mentioned in your Answer i.e. ENG UK or ENG US INTL. I guess it isnt possible to develop this outside of the Apple eco-system ?

Comment: I've switched the keyboard mapping to US INTL and tested each key. It maps almost perfectly to the Magic keyboard except as you said the `#` now replaces the `£` but interestingly I found that I can access `£` if I simultaneously press the right `option`  + left `Shift`  + `4` keys. I havent found a combination for the Euro symbol which would be useful. 
I dont suppose you know how I can type out an ascii code ? for example the ascii code the Euro would be Alt + 0128.

Comment: To use Alt codes on the Magic keyboard with Windows to produce the `€` symbol (for example),
press (left) `option/alt` + numeric keyboard `0` + `1` + `2` + `8` ....
a full MS list can be found here,
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to make a custom Windows layout to fit the printing on your Apple keyboard with [this app](http://www.kbdedit.com).

Also see this page.  The one called "English British" may take care of your issue.

[Windows Mac Layouts](https://magicutilities.net/magic-keyboard/help/keyboard-layouts)